# Android: how to achieve functionality like in facebook photo

Tags: android, image, webserver

I want to implement functionality same like in Facebook album viz. first it show blur image then clear version of that with swipe effect but I am not getting any idea from where to start from.

[image: first]

[image: second]

**EDIT**: I will be getting these images from webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik the "blurred photo" displaying in Facebook app is not actually an android feature, but more of how the embedded WebView handles images. Facebook App is basically just an embedded webview that hopes to look and feel like a native android app.

For the swiping gesture to view the next photo, you can use [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/).

Comment: thanks buddy its seems i am getting closer.webview concept will definitely be solution when i will show the image.

Answer (score 2):

Actually what happens is:

Facebook show its thumbnail image(which is already downloaded) if the large image is not loaded. So it is not intentionally blurred.

and downloads the original image in background. and then sets the large image to that `ImageView`.

[Numerous examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=android%20gallery%20example) are available to show Gallery in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a custom class extending [Android Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html)

And then try applying a blur effete on both Left and Right imageviews.