# How do I load a blurred image first, in imageview, and then make it sharp, in order to enhance user experience, for android?

Tags: android, image-processing

I'm working on an application in which I need to download lots of images. The images are to be seen in the fullscreen mode. Therefore, I wanted to know how to load an image, speedily, to make the application more responsive and enhance user experience. I would like to, atleast, show a blurred image first and than make it sharp. Thanks.

Comment: Refer this post :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291700/android-how-to-achieve-funtionality-like-in-facebook-photo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [BitmapFactory.Options.inSamleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) to load a downsampled version of the image. Then load the bigger image and do a fade transition using a [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html)

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for "progressive image rendering", which can be done in a variety of different image formats, including png, jpeg, gif, etc. The next time you're going to save an image in a good graphics program, select one of those formats and take a look at your save options.  You should have an option to save an "interlaced" image.

Jeff Atwood of Coding Horror has a nice write up here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/12/progressive-image-rendering.html

Comment: You're quite welcome - and kudos to you for coming back to say "Thanks".